# Boolean absorption

Tags: boolean-algebra

> A and ( A or C ) = A

And

> A or A and C = A

How do these identities work?

Using the rule

> A and ( B or C ) = A and B or A and C

For the first identity, I get

> A and A or A and C = A or A and C

How is the C eliminated?

Mental substitution shows that it will equal A, but can it be algebraically shown.

Equation 2, too.

Comment: Why Don't you just make a truth table?

Comment: Because, as I wrote in the question, I've already done it, mentally, and noticed that it works. I want to know why, and how it can be proven (without brute force).

Comment: What do you mean by "how to they work"? They don't "work"; they just are. What do you mean by "A or A and C"? Don't rely on everybody knowing what operator precedence you're using.

Comment: AND, before, OR, David.

Comment: @Tobi, an extra pair of parentheses for explicit readability killed exactly no one. :)

Comment: "*would kill*" *

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here is one way to prove the first identity:
$$
A \land (A \lor C) = (A \lor 0) \land (A \lor C) = A \lor (0 \land C) = A \lor 0 = A.
$$
The second identity has a similar proof. Alternatively, you could use duality to deduce it from the first identity.

Answer (score 6):

Here's one way of thinking how these identities "work". Of the first one, when *A* is false, *A and anything* is false; when *A* is true, *A or C* is true, and the whole thing is true too; therefore being equal *A* in both cases. Similarly, the second, when *A* is true, then *A or anything* is true; when *A* is false, *A and C* is false, and the whole expression is also false.